# Android override web client error

Tags: android, overriding, webclient

I am trying to override the web client but I get "HellowWebViewClient cannot be resolved to a type" error.. What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.example.name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // find the WebView by name in the main.xml of step 2
        browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvwMain);

        // Enable javascript
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

        // Set WebView client
        browser.setWebChromeClient(new HellowWebViewClient());

        // Load the webpage
        browser.loadUrl("http://www.website.com/");


    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you declared the class HellowWebViewClient?

Comment: I think nowhere.. How do I do that please? I am new to Android, just following tutorials and trying to learn..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean "HelloWebViewClient" but wrote "Hello **w** WebViewClient".

Comment: please mention this kind of things in the comment not in the answer :)

Comment: Sorry. I'm new here but i'll remember for the future !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial with example code for the WebChromeClient (what your HwllowWebViewClient should be):
http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-webview-webchromeclient-example.html

If you want to set a WebViewClient, you should check this out from the developer site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation

And here's a stackoverflow question about the differences between the two:
[What's the difference between setWebViewClient vs. setWebChromeClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835556/whats-the-difference-between-setwebviewclient-vs-setwebchromeclient)

EDIT: taking the sample WebViewClient from the developer site and renaming it for your purposes (Notice that we are setting the web view client and not the chrome client):

```
package com.example.name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView browser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // find the WebView by name in the main.xml of step 2
        browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvwMain);

        // Enable javascript
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

        // Set WebView client
        // Notice that we are setting the web view client and not the chrome client.
        browser.setWebViewClient(new HellowWebViewClient());

        // Load the webpage
        browser.loadUrl("http://www.website.com/");


    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can declare the "HellowWebViewClient" class?