# Make Espresso wait for WebView to finish loading

Tags: android, testing, webview, android-espresso

Is there a reliable way to make Espresso wait for WebViews to finish loading?

I've tried the approach outlined [here](http://dev.jimdo.com/2014/05/09/wait-for-it-a-deep-dive-into-espresso-s-idling-resources/) but found it unreliable. It also has other drawbacks:

- It relies on replacing the WebView's WebChromeClient. Any existing WebChromeClient can't be wrapped either, since WebViewrt doesn't have a getWebChromeClient() method for some reason.
- It requires a specific WebView instance, so every time I start an Activity with a WebView I have to get the WebView instance and register a new WebviewIdlingResource for it.

I'm hoping someone has a solution without any of these drawbacks. I had hopes that the espresso-web package might provide a solution, but it doesn't appear to offer anything relating to loading.

Comment: I've found this: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android/blob/a8aa3218fda2a0c72b039f371a1b5d12e522051f/app/src/androidTest/java/com/amazonaws/devicefarm/android/referenceapp/IdlingResources/WebViewIdlingResource.java

Comment: `WebView` seems to have a [getWebChromeClient()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#getWebChromeClient()) method.  Maybe it was introduced after the original problem was posted.

Answer (score 6):

As you mentioned, there is an espresso add-on called espresso-web for dealing with webviews and their content.

"finish loading" is a bit of a vague concept. It will depend on *what* specifically to you want to finish.

If you use `onWebView().check(<the you want to finish is in your webview>)` that will return only after the web view has loaded and the `check` has succeeded.

> Espresso-web is an entry point to work with WebViews on Android. It uses Atoms from the popular WebDriver API to introspect into and control the behavior of a WebView.
>
> Similar to onData, WebView interactions are actually composed of several View Atoms. An Atom can be seen as a ViewAction, a self contained unit which performs an action in your UI. However, they need to be properly orchestrated and are quite verbose. Web and WebInteraction wrap this boilerplate and give an Espresso-like feel to interacting with WebViews.

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/web

Comment: That does not answer the question

Comment: I haven't looked at this in a while, but if I remember correctly `check()` will fail immediately if the content isn't loaded yet. In other words, I need to wait for the content to load before calling it.

Comment: what @vaughandroid said

Comment: @vaughandroid I added a with timeout and it waits.

Answer (score 0):

If the unreliability experienced with [Wait for it...a deep dive into Espresso's Idling Resources](https://dev.jimdo.com/2014/05/09/wait-for-it-a-deep-dive-into-espresso-s-idling-resources/) was caused by using `WebChromeClient`, consider using `WebViewClient` instead.

I found that `WebViewClient` fires `onPageFinished()` reliably when a web page finishes loading.  `WebChromeClient` and `WebViewClient` are similar but `WebViewClient` is more general in that `WebChromeClient` handles the Chrome-specific aspects of the WebView (see [What's the difference between setWebViewClient vs. setWebChromeClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835556/whats-the-difference-between-setwebviewclient-vs-setwebchromeclient)).

In a sample project, https://github.com/mosofsky/how-to-coredux, I register the  `onPageFinished()` function to the `WebView` as follows:

```kotlin
playVideoWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        if (null != url && url != ABOUT_URL) {
            // the next line dispatches an action that calls decrement()
            howToViewModel.dispatchAction(LoadVideo_Finish)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful although admittedly I have not addressed the other drawbacks you mentioned.  As for the lack of [`getWebChromeClient()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#getWebChromeClient()), that seems to be available now.  As for requiring a specific WebView instance, I don't know how to avoid that.  Somehow you have to make the WebView decrement the idling resource counter when it's finished loading.  It seems like any solution would have to touch a specific instance of the WebView in some way to complete this registration process.  Some developers might feel it's tedious or inappropriate to litter their production code with [`CountingIdlingResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/idling/CountingIdlingResource)'s calls to [`increment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/idling/CountingIdlingResource#increment) and [`decrement()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/idling/CountingIdlingResource#decrement).

To minimize the amount of code instrumented with idling resource counting calls, you can isolate these calls to what I'll call a "side effect" of asynchronous code.  For this, I've found using a Redux data store can be very helpful, for example [CoRedux](https://github.com/freeletics/CoRedux).  When an asynchronous action begins, you can update the state to "in progress"; when it ends, clear that "in progress" flag.  The "side effect" can be any mechanism that listens for "in progress".  CoRedux literally has a construct called a "side effect" that you can use, but any mechanism that responds to state changes is fine.

In the side effect for the [how-to-coredux](https://github.com/mosofsky/how-to-coredux) sample project, it calls [`increment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/idling/CountingIdlingResource#increment) and [`decrement()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/idling/CountingIdlingResource#decrement) like this:

```kotlin
when (action) {

    is Initialize_Start, is ShowVideoFragment_Start, LoadVideo_Start, HideVideoFragment_Start -> {
        espressoTestIdlingResource.increment()
    }

    Initialize_Finish, ShowVideoFragment_Finish, LoadVideo_Finish, HideVideoFragment_Finish -> {
        espressoTestIdlingResource.decrement()
    }
}
```

By isolating the idling resource logic to a side effect, an entire Android project could rely on a single piece of code for calling `increment()`/`decrement()` every time any asynchronous UI event begins/ends, respectively.