# WebView in Fragment not loading page

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have put a `WebView` in the layout of my Fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.deped.k12.GradeSheet"
    android:background="#fafafa">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />

</FrameLayout>
```

But when I try to load any website from it. I just get a blank `WebView`:
[image]

I tried looking for error messages in the Android Monitor but there are none.

Here's the code I use in the Fragment to load a URL:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grade_sheet, container, false);

        String url = "http://www.google.com/";
        WebView wv = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        });
        final String mimeType = "text/html";
        final String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String html = "";
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, html, mimeType, encoding, "");


        return view;
    }
```

I also added the correct permission:

[image]

What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

I don't really know if you just have to add a WebViewClient.

More informations: [WebViewClient vs WebChromeClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835556/whats-the-difference-between-setwebviewclient-vs-setwebchromeclient)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is:

```
String html = "";
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

You're loading your empty `html` String into the webview.

Try something like: `wv.loadUrl("http://example.com/");` instead or update your `html` string accordingly.

You should have a look at the API documentation for the [loadDataWithBaseURL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.