# is it possible to run a simple html that calls a js file on android?

Tags: javascript, android

I created a simple local page that has a square in it and it calls a JavaScript file that has functions which animate that square. It works fine on my computer's web browser, but on my Android browser the square is static and JavaScript file is not loaded. How can I make the animation work on android?

My HTML:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code and not just an image of your code.

Comment: Improved grammar

Comment: Check if javascript is enabled on your android browser first of all

Comment: look at his link and read, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835556/whats-the-difference-between-setwebviewclient-vs-setwebchromeclient/41323968#41323968

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a web view you can load an HTML file, and any referenced JavaScript will run.

Checkout the developer docs on WebView! Totally rocks!

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html