# Android Webview - Change Elements with Javascript after page finished loading

Tags: javascript, android, dom, webview

I want to change some values on a HTML Page, using Javascript in a Webview.
I tried many different ways to evaluate Javscript after page finished loading.

Here is my code:

```
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('options').value = '" + found.getId() + "'; ;})()");
            button.performClick();

        }
    });
```

I think it means, that the method is called to early, before page is fully loaded.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in order to change value / content / styling in HTML using javascript also known as *DOM Manipulate*, then we have waiting after DOM ready or fully loaded. In this case, we load the page into widget **WebView** and then do our business.

I have a sample code that I always use in the same case,

```java
...

    final String url = "http://example.com";
    final WebView webview = findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
    final String myNewValue = "it works!";

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // Your custom javascript here
            String myCustomJS = "document.getElementById('options').innerHTML = '" +
                     myNewValue + "'";

            // here we execute the javascript code
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" + myCustomJS + "})()");
        }
    });

    // and here we load the url
    webview.loadUrl(url);

...
```

I hope the code above can help you to continue working..

---

> Update for **Waiting DOM Ready**

If you have use **jQuery** before, then you must know

```
// example 1: jQuery way
$(document).ready(function() {
    // place our logic here
});

// example 2: native javascript way
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // place our logic here
});
```

Im use this trick to manipulate page in WebView after DOM ready (in **example 2** native JS way).

*Another question why not using runnable?*

> because we never know internet speed users, let say if we set runnable to wait `3000ms` or `3sec` but the web not responding after runnable execution. **What happened next?** users will have white blank screen and keep waiting.

hope this more clear now.

reference link: [https://developer.mozilla.org/.../DOMContentLoaded_event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I will try it later. But what makes the difference in your code?

Comment: @SimonLiebers my code above call **WebChromeClient** too, [reference from another question SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835556/whats-the-difference-between-setwebviewclient-vs-setwebchromeclient) might be help you. If you just want to load web url then WebViewClient enough for do that. But in many case i always facing same issue when my custom JS not work using **WebViewClient**, after many search on Internet. Finally i found why my custom JS not work, then im only call **WebChromeClient** as magic. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: For me it does not change anything. But if i call the javascript in a handler, after delay, it works... @ian cikal

Comment: @SimonLiebers the point is we have waiting after DOM ready, after that we can manipulate it in many way using JS. or in your case send value from Android into **WebView**,

Comment: Ok makes sense, but how can i wait for DOM? @ian cikal

Comment: @SimonLiebers please see my update, hope the answer more clear now.

Comment: Is it possible to inject the EventListener in Java, before the Event is triggered?

Comment: please correct if am wrong, did you mean **Java** or **Javascript** ? If you mean javascript, as i know we can execute javascript code before DOM ready. usage like **async**, **await** in promise ES6. but for manipulate elements or event change value inside element. The answer is NO, because The **DOMContentLoaded** event is only way to doing that stuff after DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. But if you mean **Java**, you can use **Asynctask** or **Service**

Comment: I want to use Java (Android Studio) to inject code inside Webview (loadURL(javascript: document.getElementById...). The code should executed when dom has loaded.